# Dynamically hide/show properties based on the selection in a CheckComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed

In WPF I'd like to have such a view model, that in a `PropertyGrid` it should display a [`CheckComboBox`](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/CheckComboBox) enabling me to dynamically show/hide other properties (based on the selection).

I populate the `CheckComboBox` with the content of the following property:

```cs
// A collection used as the data source for the CheckComboBox.
[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
public ObservableCollection<TriggerTypeItem> TriggerTypes { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TriggerTypeItem>();
```

where `TriggerTypeItem` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

However, it seems that changes to `TriggerTypeItem` elements doesn't cause the `TriggerTypes` attribute to be considered modified and thus - the dynamic change of `Browsable` attribute is not reflected in the property grid.
(The `SetBrowsableAttribute()` function works correctly, as you can see by toogling the `ShouldShow` property's checkbox.)

What should I do to achieve the desired behavior?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfPlayground.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <xctk:PropertyGrid x:Name="PropertyGridControl">
            <xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
                <xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition TargetProperties="TriggerTypes">
                    <xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <xctk:CheckComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Instance.TriggerTypes}"
                                                DisplayMemberPath="TriggerType"
                                                SelectedMemberPath="Selected" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
                </xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition>
            </xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
        </xctk:PropertyGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfPlayground
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly EventViewModel eventViewModel = new EventViewModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PropertyGridControl.SelectedObject = eventViewModel;
        }
    }

    public abstract class PropertyChangedBase : Component, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void NotifyOfPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public enum TriggerType
    {
        Timer,
    }

    public class EventViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private bool _shouldShow;
        private readonly Dictionary<TriggerType, string> _triggerViewModels = new Dictionary<TriggerType, string>()
        {
            { TriggerType.Timer, nameof(ToogleProperty) }
        };

        // A "regular" checkbox for toogling.
        [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
        public bool ShouldShow
        {
            get { return _shouldShow; }
            set
            {
                TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[nameof(ToogleProperty)].SetBrowsableAttribute(value);

                _shouldShow = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(ShouldShow));
            }
        }

        // A collection used as the data source for the CheckComboBox.
        [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
        public ObservableCollection<TriggerTypeItem> TriggerTypes { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TriggerTypeItem>();

        // The property to be toogled.
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public string ToogleProperty { get; set; } = "(Toggle me!)";

        public EventViewModel()
        {
            ShouldShow = true;
            foreach (TriggerType val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TriggerType)))
            {
                TriggerTypes.Add(new TriggerTypeItem(triggerType: val, eventModel: this) { Selected = false });
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dynamically sets the <c>Browsable</c> attribute.
        /// </summary>
        public void UpdatePropertyGridTriggers(TriggerType triggerType, bool newBrowsableState)
        {
            if (_triggerViewModels.TryGetValue(triggerType, out string propertyName))
            {
                TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName].SetBrowsableAttribute(newBrowsableState);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An item in the CheckCoboBox.
    /// </summary>
    public class TriggerTypeItem : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private TriggerType _triggerType;
        private bool _selected;

        public EventViewModel EventModel { get; private set; }

        public TriggerType TriggerType
        {
            get { return _triggerType; }
            set
            {
                _triggerType = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(TriggerType));
            }
        }

        public bool Selected
        {
            get { return _selected; }
            set
            {
                if (_selected != value)
                {
                    _selected = value;
                    EventModel?.UpdatePropertyGridTriggers(TriggerType, value);
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(Selected));
                }
            }
        }

        public TriggerTypeItem(TriggerType triggerType, EventViewModel eventModel)
        {
            EventModel = eventModel;
            TriggerType = triggerType;
        }
    }

    public static class PropertyDescriptorExtensions
    {
        /// See: http://www.reza-aghaei.com/make-a-property-read-only-in-propertygrid/ (Solution #2)
        public static void SetBrowsableAttribute(this PropertyDescriptor p, bool value)
        {
            var attributes = p.Attributes.Cast<Attribute>().Where(x => !(x is BrowsableAttribute)).ToList();
            attributes.Add(new BrowsableAttribute(value));
            typeof(MemberDescriptor).GetProperty("AttributeArray", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(p, attributes.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObservableCollection in WPF does not propagate the NotifyPropertyChanged event. Thus, the RefreshProperties event does not fire when the TriggerTypeItems are changed. One way of overcoming this could be to force the NotifyPropertyChanged event to occur by changing the `NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(propertyName));` in UpdatePropertyGridTriggers to `NotifyPropertyChange("")`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've spent a few hours today looking for the solution - never thought it would be so simple :)

Comment: Just to note, NotifyPropertyChange("") will send the NotifyPropertyChange event for all your properties in the class in case this may affect your future usecase